# How to show only running applications in the Sound Indicator

Tags: 13.10, indicator-sound

How to show only the running applications in the Sound Indicator (not all supported). After upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 this is how it looks.

[image: sound menu]

Answer (score 0):

With dconf-tools (*sudo apt-get install dconf-tools*), you can edit com>canonical>indicator>sound to your needs.

Simply edit the string "interested media players" and remove those you don't want.

I don't know any other way except forking source to edit this indicator.

Comment: The question is how to hide the apps that are not used at the moment.

Comment: Mmh... Maybe you should look into Cinnamon's desktop files (like .json or in dconf), it has this option built-in. Maybe 13.04 had it too, I never used Unity with 13.04. I can't help you further :/